# Can I safely use my MacBook Pro HDD late 2011 with a late 2009?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a GPU issue with my MacBook Pro late 2011 which requires 3 weeks in repair (until the required parts come in). I took out the hard drive and put it in an external casing.

Can I safely use this hard drive on another MacBook Pro (late 2009) and still use my data/applications/OS X?

Comment: What OS X are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to [this document](https://www.apple.com/support/osx/upgrade/) Macs that can run either Mountain Lion or Mavericks are good for Yosemite. The oldest MacBook Pro you can use is therefore Mid/Late 2007. So in any case you should be fine.

[OS X Mavericks: System Requirements](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201364):

> To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:
>
> - iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
> - MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
> - MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
> - MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
> - Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
> - Xserve (Early 2009)
>
> Your Mac also needs:
>
> - OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed
> - 2 GB or more of memory
> - 8 GB or more of available space

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the OS X version you are using. If the Late 2011 and Late 2009 HDD have Yosemite, then you are good. But if Late 2009 has other than Yosemite and 2011 has Yosemite, then some apps will refuse to run.